# presto sql filter part of the string java

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a string in col1 `select col1 from table`

`"blah blah 123 blah iterate 866 loss blah blah"`

how to filter string between `iterate`  and `loss`  and just show sum of all such filtered numbers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_extract`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?#regexp_extract) to extract the number within that string, convert the values to a numeric type and sum them up:

```sql
WITH t(v) AS (
    VALUES 'blah blah 123 blah iterate 866 loss blah blah'
)
SELECT sum(CAST(regexp_extract(v, 'iterate (\d+) loss', 1) AS bigint)) 
FROM t
```