# sql filter two dates from a string and calculate the difference

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a string in col1 `select col1 from table;`

`blah blah from 2020-02-18T04:45:16.099-08:00[PST8PDT] to 2020-04-02T08:45:16.099-07:00[PST8PDT] blah blah`

how to filter dates after `from`  and `to`  and calculate the difference in days ?

Comment: What SQL are you using? T-SQL (SQL Server/Azure SQL), PL/SQL (Oracle), MySQL, something else? For that variant of SQL, have you looked up how to set a date range in a `WHERE` clause, or how to calculate the difference between two dates?

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`regex_extract`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract) to get the "from" part and the "to" part out of the string (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66360995/65458 for more info)
- Then use [`from_iso8601_timestamp`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp) to convert date/time string into a `timestamp(3) with time zone`.
- Then use [subtract on the date/time values](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) to calculate `interval day to seconds`
- Then use `day` to extract day portion of the interval.

Example sans the regex extraction:

```
trino> SELECT day(from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-04-02T08:45:16.099-07:00')
    ->          - from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-02-18T04:45:16.099-08:00'));
 _col0
-------
    44
(1 row)
```

(Tested with Trino 352)